# React: "Warning: Unknown DOM property itemscope. Did you mean itemScope?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, microdata, package.json

I am using **React 15.6.1** and trying to insert some Microdata into my text:

```html
<div itemScope itemType="http://schema.org/VideoGame">
```

But I keep seeing the following warning in the console:

> Warning: Unknown DOM property itemscope. Did you mean itemScope?

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1491), it should work.

Anyone could help me and figure out what is wrong?
Is my version of React too old or do I have to define a flag somewhere to get it to work ?

This is my package.json: (I am using **npm start** to debug, and **npm run build** to deploy)

```json
{
    "name": "P",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": ".",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
        "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
        "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
        "serve-favicon": "^2.4.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.3.13",
        "circular-dependency-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
        "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
        "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
        "firebase": "^4.1.3",
        "history": "^4.6.3",
        "immutable": "^3.8.1",
        "invariant": "^2.2.2",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "jsdom": "^11.1.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
        "konva": "^1.6.3",
        "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.0",
        "react-async-script": "^0.9.1",
        "react-async-script-loader": "^0.3.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.1",
        "react-dnd": "^2.4.0",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.4.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
        "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
        "react-ga": "^2.2.0",
        "react-google-recaptcha": "^0.9.6",
        "react-gravatar": "^2.6.3",
        "react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
        "react-input-range": "^1.2.1",
        "react-konva": "^1.1.3",
        "react-modal": "^2.2.2",
        "react-page-click": "^4.0.1",
        "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.2",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
        "react-router": "^3.0.2",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-form": "^7.0.1",
        "redux-logger": "^2.3.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
        "single-module-instance-webpack-plugin": "0.0.4",
        "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
        "superagent": "^3.5.2",
        "webpack": "^3.3.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
        "xmldom": "^0.1.27",
        "xpath": "0.0.24"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node devServer.js --progress --verbose",
        "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
        "dev": "webpack -d --watch --progress --display-error-details --display-reasons",
        "start1": "webpack-dev-server  --config ./webpack.config.comphotdeploy -d --progress --colors --host localhost --port 28080 --hot --inline --content-base src",
        "builddev": "webpack -d --progress --display-error-details --display-reasons",
        "build": "webpack -p --progress --verbose",
        "dist": "rimraf ./dist&&webpack -d --display-error-details --display-reasons",
        "start-react": "SET PORT=9999&&SET DEVTOOL=source-map&&react-scripts start",
        "build-react": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear out your browser cache (or eslint or nodejs server cache, even...) and run again? Because all works as expected for me with this simplistic markup: `<div itemScope itemType="http://schema.org/VideoGame">CONTENT</div>`. Also, try to remove this package: `babel-plugin-react-html-attrs`, it may be causing probs [for possibly unknown reasons...].

Comment: I don’t know React, but am curious: Is there a reason for using `itemScope`/`itemType` instead of `itemscope`/`itemtype`?

Comment: When you use react, you have to use the uppercasing like I wrote.
Quoted from the React site:
`React uses camelCased attributes, so it should be itemProp, itemType and itemScope (it will still appear lower-cased in the DOM)`

Comment: Clearing the browser cache and remove the `babel-plugin-react-html-attrs` did not change anything. I am still getting the same warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem, one of the itemScope was declared as itemscope.
I did not see it because it was outside of the editor window as part of a long string.